# Style radio groups differently from each other

Tags: drupal-7

I have a form I'm trying to build in Druapal 7, I managed to use theme_radio to style the first group of radio buttons so that they have the class 'visible-xs' on the label to hide the label from anything but phones (as it's displayed in a table heading for desktop). That works fine, but now I have a second group of radios that need the label visible on all devices but I don't know how to make this happen since all of the radios share the same code.

How am I supposed to do this in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [theme_radio](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_radio/7) only for a specific form and not for all forms.

If you mean that you have the 2 radio groups inside the same form then I suggest using the [theme_radios()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radios/7) function which is most appropriate.

If none of these work for you please provide the code you are using and the html output (of the form).